# should('exist') working in my system but same code is not working in another system & CI/CD pipeline

Tags: cypress

should('exist') working in my system but  same code is not working in github action file

Even though the installation & version is also same am getting below error in github action :

```
1) Customer Page - Partner
       Create New customer:
     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: `//p[text()='Customer created successfully!']`, but never found it.
      at Context.eval (webpack://csc-external-ui-automation/./cypress/e2e/Customer.cy.js:69:38)
```

```
it('Create New customer', () => {
    
    CustPage.UAM_Page().click()
    CustPage.CustomerIcon().should('be.visible')
    CustPage.CustomerIcon().click()
    CustPage.NewCustomerButton().should('be.visible')
    CustPage.NewCustomerButton().click()
    CustPage.CustomerFormHeader().should('be.visible')
      .should('have.text', 'New customer')

    // Adding New Customer
    CustPage.LegalNameInput().type(LegalName,{ force: true })
    CustPage.BrandNameInput().type(BrandName,{ force: true })
    CustPage.ContactEmailInput().type(contactemail,{ force: true })
    CustPage.InternalRefInput().type(Internalref,{ force: true })
    CustPage.AddNewCustomerButton().click()
   
   CustPage.CustomerCreated_Message().should('exist')
})
```

github Action yaml

````
name: Chrome

on: push

jobs:
  chrome:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Chrome
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        timeout-minutes: 10
        with:
          build: npm run test
          start: npm test
          browser: chrome
        ```
````

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What happens instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: CI/CD can be slower than locally run tests. If you are getting a "could not find" error try increasing the timeout of `CustomerUpdated_Message()`.

Comment: BTW `.should('exist')` should not be needed if `CustomerUpdated_Message()` uses `cy.get()`.

Comment: Increasing timeout is not helping out check the detailed code above , pls suggest whats the issue

Comment: Sadly, your detail omits the code of CustPage, so that's no clearer.